# Shower head won't screw back

Tags: bathroom, shower, screws

I removed the shower head for cleaning it, but now I can't screw it back anymore: the threads won't click into one-another (unless I remove the gasket so that the two ends can get closer to each other, but then of course the head is no use anymore, because the water will flow from the base too).
What I tried was pressing the head and the tube together (with the gasket in), but even then, the threads don't reach eachother.

**Question:** is there some trick to screw it back together, or should I just buy a new one?

Comment: Did you check to ensure the gasket was seated as deep as possible?

Comment: Yeah, I tried to push it down as far as it went... no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might be best to just by a new one, however, one thing you could try is some plumbing tape (PTFE tape, or Teflon Tape). This tape is generally used to help seal screw connections on plumbing but could provide the extra grip between the threads needed to keep it connected.

Comment: Thanks, TIL about PTFE. One question: would this be _instead_ of the gasket (because it seals the connection), or would this just improve the grip of the threads, but I would still need the gasket to make it water proof?

Comment: You would still want the gasket. This only helps to seal the threads from leaking and may provide the extra grip needed to get it to screw on correctly. As noted though, if the threads are stripped on the shower head it may be better just to replace it.